# Why does "typedef struct anything_at_all boom;" compile without errors?

Tags: c

Why does

```
//The type anything_at_all exists nowhere.
typedef struct anything_at_all lol;
```

compile without errors, whereas

```
//The type anything_at_all_2 exists nowhere.
typedef anything_at_all_2 rofl;
```

produces errors?

What's so special about structs? In a way I'm glad it works like this because it allows us to create opaque structs. But it would be nice to understand *why* it works.

Comment: Because `struct anything_at_all` is an incomplete type. `anything_at_all_2` is not.

Comment: The compiler cannot confirm what type of identifier (value or type and if it's a type then what kind of type) `anything_at_all_2` is, whereas for `struct anything_at_all`  it's pretty clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can declare a `struct` without defining it.  This is called a **forward declaration**.  It allows you to do things like this:

```
struct s1;

struct s2 {
    int x;
    struct s1 *p;
};

struct s1 {
    int y;
    struct s2 *p;
};
```